# port forwarding apache

Tags: apache, xampp, portforwarding

I want XAMPP to be accessible from my internet IP address.

The problem is that the router login page is displayed when I type in my internet IP address. I think it uses port `80`.

I have manually set my IP address to `192.168.5.44`.

I have changed the default port of Apache from port `80` to port `6065`
and port forwarded this port.

It is accessible using the IP address `192.168.5.44:6065`

I have forwarded the ports from 6065-6070 in my router settings. I have confirmed from canyouseeme.org that port 6065 is accessible from my internet IP address.

When I access `http://113.203.158.164:6065` (`113.203.158.164` is my internet IP address and port `6065` is of apache) I get an error. This confuses me because my static ip `192.168.5.44:6065` opens up the XAMPP page.

```
Unable to connect
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 113.203.158.164:6065.
```

Answer (score 0):

You XAMPP configuration is accessible to the internet via the listed link, so it is working.

Maybe it can't be mapped to your own ip this way?

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you need to first clear your concepts :

- 1 The IP you set 192.168.5.44, is the local IP of your system. It will be visible to all the systems in your LAN only.
- 2 The port 6065 you configured for apache is the port of your machine used to apache to run its service, it is has no correlation with the ports on your router.
- 3 So, when you input http://192.168.5.44:6065 it will always work from any machine in your LAN , no matter what your router settings for internet are
- 4 For you to host your service online, you need to check that 113.203.158.164 is static internet IP obtained from your SP.
- 5 Port 6065 of your router must be open , NOTE : This is different from the port 6065 in your system in which your service is hosted. Ideally you could just select to forward port 80 to 80 in router settings. So that any incoming request on 113.203.158.164 is by default forwarded.
- 6 You must put the IP 192.168.5.44 in the option for forwarding to, and put the port no. 6065 (now, this stands for the port of your service , running on your system) in the adjoining option , this signifies where the request received on your 113.203.158.164 :80/6065 (whichever port you chose to forward) is forwarded to!